# How to use BytesIO with matplotlib and pyqt5?

Tags: python, matplotlib, io, pyqt5, bytesio

I made a graph in matplotlib, and wanted to make it in to an image and use it in my pyqt5 application. Someone suggested I use BytesIO for this. This is my code so far:

Drawing my graph:

```
...
plt.axis('equal')
buff = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buff, format="png")
print(buff)
return buff
```

This is then called in another script:

```
def minionRatioGraphSetup(self, recentMinionRatioAvg):
    image = minionRatioGraph(recentMinionRatioAvg)
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image)
    label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0,200,200))
```

It stops working at `pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image)` and I'm unsure why. Also: How could I place this in my MainWindow? because I doubt the code there will work lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a solution using a buffer. However, it seems rather complicated to get the byte format correct. So an alternative is to save the image to disk, and then load it from there.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def minionRatioGraph():
    plt.plot([1,3,2])
    plt.savefig(__file__+".png", format="png")


class App(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        label = QtGui.QLabel()
        label2 = QtGui.QLabel("Some other text label") 

        minionRatioGraph()

        qimg = QtGui.QImage(__file__+".png")  
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(qimg)

        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.layout().addWidget(label)
        self.layout().addWidget(label2)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thanks man, you're a lifesaver. I've been pulling my hair out over this haha

Answer (score 1):

a snippet using pillow, might help avoiding file io

```
 im = PIL.Image.open("filename")
 with BytesIO() as f:
     im.save(f, format='png')
     f.seek(0)
     image_data = f.read()
     qimg = QImage.fromData(image_data)
     patch_qt = QPixmap.fromImage(qimg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that only uses the buffer, you need to use PIL to create an ImageQT and then load it to the QPixap

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PIL import Image

...

buff = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buff, format="png")
img = Image.open(buff)
img_qt = ImageQt(img)
return img_qt
```

Then, in your GUI setup, you call your function to return the ImageQT and generate the QPixmap using QPixmap.fromImage()

```
def minionRatioGraphSetup(self, recentMinionRatioAvg):
    image = minionRatioGraph(recentMinionRatioAvg)
    label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
    label.setPixmap(pixmap)
    label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0,200,200))
```